# Why does decreasing the range of np.linspace increase the accuracy of numerical integration?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration

Reading a tutorial on simple numerical integration (https://helloacm.com/how-to-compute-numerical-integration-in-numpy-python/), which seems to suggest that decreasing the range of the x values used in your function returns a more accurate numerical answer.  The code the use is

```
def integrate(f, a, b, N):
    x = np.linspace(a, b, N)
    fx = f(x)
    area = np.sum(fx)*(b-a)/N
    return area

integrate(np.sin, 0, np.pi/2, 100)
```

This returns a value of 0.99783321217729803.

However when they modify the integration method to:

```
def integrate(f, a, b, N):
    x = np.linspace(a+(b-a)/(2*N), b-(b-a)/(2*N), N)
    fx = f(x)
    area = np.sum(fx)*(b-a)/N
    return area

integrate(np.sin, 0, np.pi/2, 100)
```

This returns a more accurate value of 1.0000102809119051.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong but looks like the number of steps is maintained, so decreasing the range actually decreases the step size -> more accuracy

Comment: But does changing the range of integration not alter the answer?  Integrating sin(x) from 0 to pi/2 = 1, but from 0+k to pi/2-k < 1 isn't it?

Comment: You change the range of the sampling points, not the integration range: in your `area` computation you still use `(b-a)`, but you have more points in the interval for the second case

Comment: How does the sampling range differ from the integration range?  I would've thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: In the first case the position of the sample relative to the integration bin changes. It starts at the left end of the leftmost bin and moves to the right in small steps.When reaching the rightmost bin it will have moved to the very right bin end. The second case samples each bin at its center. (This is the optimal location for a binwise linear integrand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- The step width in your first `integrate` is not `(b-a) / N`, but `(b-a) / (N-1)`.
- In your first method, the error is dominated by the half-bar overshoot on the left and right, i.e., the `(b-a)/(N-1)/2 * f(a)` and `(b-a)/(N-1)/2 * f(b)`. If your subtract those two, you get an accuracy in comparable to your second method.